# While (*s) - How does this work?

Tags: c

How does this while loop works? When this *s argument terminates?

```
void putstr (char *s)  
{   
while (*s) putchar(*s++);  
}
```

So other notable behaviors, arguments for while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical expressions in C evaluate to false if they are 0, otherwise they evaluate to true. Thus your loop will terminate when `*s` is equal to 0. In the context of a `char` that is when the null-terminating character is encountered.

Note that `++` has a higher precedence than pointer dereferencing `*` and so the `++` is bound to the pointer rather than the `char` to which it points. Thus the body of your loop will call `putchar` for the character that `s` points to, and then increment the pointer `s`.

Answer (score 4):

*s dereferences into a char, which in the loop, a zero (0, or '\0') will act as false, terminating the loop, all other non-zero characters keep it as true.

Answer (score 3):

The char (`*s`) gets cast to int, for conditions it holds that any integer != 0 is interpreted as `true`, so the loop ands when a `'\0'` char is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Because the loop itself modifies `s` (with `*s++`), the while condition can examine it each time around the loop, and it will eventually terminate, when the pointer points to a nul character.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (*s)
```

while the character pointed by s is not zero (that is, if we did't reach the end of the string)

```
putchar(*s++);
```

it can be thought as

```
putchar(*s);      // write the character pointed by s
s += 1;          // go to next one
```

Comment: If `f(*s++)` was `f(*s); *s += 1;` it would be an infinite loop and wouldn't ever touch anything beyond the first character. It's `f(*s); s += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

s is a pointer on a string.
The end of a string is detected by a 0 value